# How to Pass Values from TextArea to another view on ASP .NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

im new to all this MVC4 and ASP .NET, im trying to make a simple form to get a text and then submit it to another view and print it there, i already searched tutorials and dat dere, still not getting how to do it, i made the form view and get the value to go to the controller, here is my code:

Controller:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication10.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modifique esta plantilla para poner en marcha su aplicación ASP.NET MVC.";

            return View();

       }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string text) {

            return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Página de descripción de la aplicación.";

            return View();
        }


}
```

View

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Página principal";
}

<h3>Formulario</h3>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())

    {
        @Html.Label("Escribe lo que quieras")<br />
        @Html.TextArea("text")<br />

        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>

    }
```

thats what i have so far.

Comment: you need a "for" helper (except display) to tie your data to the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> get a text and then submit it to another view and print it there

You can use either [TempData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.tempdata%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) or [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.140%29.aspx). For your scenario,TempData could be a best choice.

```
...

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string text)
{
    TempData["Text"] = text;
    return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
}

public ActionResult About()
{
    ViewBag.Message = TempData["Text"];
    return View();
}
```